# How can i encypt and decrypt file using yubico (public and private key)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fido-u2f, yubico

I try to encrypt a file using yubico public key and decrypt using yubico private key. But I am unable to generate private and public key from yubico.
I already develop some example of fido2 with yubico. but it is not working properly.

Comment: Generally, you can either [generate the keys directly on the YubiKey](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Key_generation.html), or generate them [outside of the device](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/Generating_keys_using_OpenSSL.html), and then importing them into the YubiKey. The embedded links refer to the corresponding sections of the developer documentation. This is also applicable for FIDO2

Comment: I think you might be confusing FIDO/U2F application with X.509 or PGP. The former does not support file encryption, and its key pair is generated internally on the device. It can only be used for challenge-response authentication, not for encrypting files.

Comment: If you want to be able to encrypt files, you can look into 2 apps residing on the device: OpenPGP and PIV (X.509). The most convenient one for encryption is OpenPGP, since it works seamlessly with GnuPG applications on different platforms. Also, it is very to easy to use with Python's gnupg module.